# How to process multiple background concurrent Tasks in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to work out the best way to go about a task which relys on multiple long running tasks taking place.

My use case is that I want to have multiple events running for set periods of time, where I have websocket connections to each event for that period.

My thoughts were that I keep a conurrent list of all active events, when a new event pops into the list, it spawns a new thread to handle the event, when the event pops off the list, this thread will be closed.

Is this a good way to go about it?  I am trying to set up a proof of concept, where all I am doing is logging out the event ID to the console for now, it kind of works, but I haven't worked out a way to remove the thread yet etc.

Any advise anyone can give I would be really appreciative.

```
public class EventProcessingService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<EventProcessingService> _logger;
    private readonly ICacheService _cacheService;
    private const int MaxThreads = 10;
    private static readonly CountdownEvent cde = new CountdownEvent(MaxThreads);

    public static readonly BlockingCollection<int> eventIds = new BlockingCollection<int>();

    ConcurrentBag<int> EventIdsProcessing = new ConcurrentBag<int>();

    private Timer _timer = null!;

    public EventProcessingService(ILogger<EventProcessingService> logger, ICacheService cacheService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _cacheService = cacheService;

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxThreads; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Process, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object? state)
    {
        var ids = _cacheService.GetCachedEventIds();

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            if (!EventIdsProcessing.Contains(id))
            {
                EventIdsProcessing.Add(id);
                eventIds.Add(id);
            }
        }

        cde.Wait();
    }

    private async Task Process()
    {
        foreach (var id in eventIds.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            cde.Signal();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to conflate tasks with threads. When using tasks, you have no direct control over threads or whether tasks run concurrently or not. In principle, it is possible for an async application to run in a single-threaded environment - but then you're obviously limited to one concurrent task at a time. Tasks are intentionally an abstraction above the thread pool management, because managing a thread pool is often much more than you're bargaining for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `private` members

- I know naming is hard and MSDN has a [lots of bad examples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent?view=net-6.0) but `cde` is not a really good name

  - Try to capture what does it limit, like

    - `ConcurrentProcessThrottler`
    - `ConcurrentProcessLimiter`
    - etc.
- Same applies for `_timer`, try to capture the essence why did you introduce it

  - I'm not sure that you really need to use the [null-forgiving / damn-it operator](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/05/25/lying-to-the-compiler/)
- Please try to follow consistent naming pattern

  - Inconsistent: `EventIdsProcessing`, `_cacheService`, `cde`, etc.
  - Either use underscore prefix for all your `private` members or do not prefix them
- I know it is a POC but I would suggest to receive the `maxThreads` as a constructor parameter rather than using a hard-coded `const`

  - [Tasks are not Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429129/task-vs-thread-differences), so a way better name would be

    - `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`
    - `ThresholdForMaxConcurrency`
    - etc.

#### `public` member

- Please try to use Pascal Casing for public member (`eventIds`)

  - It is unclear why it should be `public`

#### `EventProcessingService` constructor

- Try to express your intent by using the [discard operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards)

  - If you want to just fire off a new `Task` and you don't care about the `Task` itself then make this intent explicit

```
_ = Task.Factory.StartNew(Process, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

- Here the `StartNew` returns a `Task<Task>` so you need to call `Unwrap` to have a flattened `Task`

  - Please prefer `Task.Run` over `StartNew` since the latter one might be [dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

#### `Process`

- Using `GetConsumingEnumerable` works fine if the producer side calls the `CompleteAdding` to signal it will not produce new elements
- I assume that your infinite loop simulates some real processing logic

  - Based on your code I don't see how will it move from the first element to the next since you have an infinite loop inside the loop body

#### `StartAsync`

- I do believe you should kick off your concurrent `Process` workers/consumers here, not inside the constructor

  - With that you would be able to pass the `CancellationToken` to the `Task.Run` and to the `Process` as well
- I would also recommend to add protection against multiple `StartAsync` calls

  - A `StartAsync` should have any affect only if it was not called before or if there was a completed `StopAsync` prior it

#### `DoWork`

- It took me a couple of seconds to realize that `DoWork` has to match to `TimerCallback` delegate that's why it has a `object? state` parameter

  - Please consider to add a comment there for future maintainers or to enhance legibility
- As I said several times please try to use better naming

  - Here your `DoWork` acts like a single producer, please try to capture this information inside the method name
- Please bear in my that `ConcurrentBag` is thread-safe if you perform atomic operation

  - Performing `Contains` then `Add` is not atomic << not thread-safe
  - Please consider to use `lock` or use `ConcurrentDictionary` which does expose [`TryAdd`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryadd?view=net-6.0)

#### `Dispose`

- Please try to implement the [Dispose pattern as it should be](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response, I will read it all through properly and make the changes.